# Is there a method in Java 8 to make a Thread sleep until an Instant using a specific Clock?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Given a Clock, an Instant and the current Thread, is there already some (utility) method in the Java libraries that makes the current thread sleep until the given clock reaches the instant?

Something like

```
public static void sleepUntil(Instant instant, Clock clock) 
 throws InterruptedException;
```

?

I need this in a test setting where I am working with a custom slowed-down clock.

I know that it is easy to implement, but I would prefer a standard solution if available (but didn't find it so far).

Comment: Actually, maybe not so easy to implement...

Comment: Maybe you could somehow convert to [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) and call its `sleep`?

Comment: No, because there seems to be no possibility to make TimeUnit aware of the custom clock.

Comment: Unless you want to poll the `Clock` repeatedly, there isn’t even a hard way to implement what you want.

Comment: Yep, I think the only possibility to do it without frequent polling would be in the clocks implementation itself, making use of the knowldege about the respective clocks inner workings. Sadly, Clock doesn't define a suitable method, so let's wait for Java 12.

Comment: Why not just wait on some object associated with the clock and have the clock notify items when it ticks over?  If you're reimplementing cron with a custom time-keeper, you can still use wait-notify and have interested parties wait on different objects if they're interested in the next day tick versus the next second tick.

Comment: Yes you could do that, but this would mean you have to extend Clock (standard clocks have no associated thread that could tick), use that custom clock everywhere, cast at many places, wrap the standard Clock implementations so that they extend the custom Clock class and so on. Maybe I'll do that, but its extremely ugly and a utility method is probably more pragmatic.

Comment: @Holger: If the clock is slowed-down by a fixed amount, it may be possible. See [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32921070/1587329).

Comment: @user: sure, but that knowledge is already off-API.

Comment: In general, the operating system facilities that could provide this kind of functionality do not guarantee thread wake up at the precise instant, but rather guarantee wake-up at or after an instant.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) is a **really simple** class with little [implementation](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/jdk/src/share/classes/java/time/Clock.java) and [few uses in the standard API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/class-use/Clock.html). `SystemClock`, `OffsetClock` and `TickClock` are examples in the same file. So the answer seems to be **No, it is not in the [default API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/class-use/Clock.html)**.

If you are given the "slowed-down clock" and may not modify it to add the desired `sleepUntil()`-code, and it is **slowed down by a fixed amount**, you could do something like

```
public static void sleepUntil(Instant instant, Clock clock) 
    throws InterruptedException {

    Instant now = Instant.now(clock);
    long duration = now.until(instant, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    long testSleep
        = ( duration < 10000 )? (duration / 10) : 1000;
    long start = clock.millis();
    Thread.sleep(testSleep);
    long stop = clock.millis();
    double clockskew = (stop - start) / testSleep;

    now = Instant.now(clock);
    Thread.sleep(now.until(instant, ChronoUnit.MILLIS) * clockskew);
}
```

This first does a test run to determine the clock skew, then *sleeps an adjusted duration*.

(Maybe you need to adjust the instant in `sleep` to adjust to the other clock. Post your clock code if you wish to have it tested/adjusted.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was needed to wait for a particular time.
My solution.

```
long expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60_000;
Thread.sleep(expirationTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Another way is to do it with `do-while` but actually, I couldn't see its advantages.

Answer (score -2):

The only way I can see to do that is to create a while loop and break from it when the clock has reached the given instant.

```
public static void sleepUntil(Instant instant, Clock clock) throws InterruptedException {
    while (clock.millis() < instant.toEpochMilli()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

For fixed clock, this would loop forever though.

Comment: That doesn't work, because Thread.sleep(long millis) uses the system clock and not the custom clock.